# Magento include phtml file within another phtml file

Tags: tags, magento-1.9, php

I am making a custom home page for my magento website in a phtml file named home_banner.phtml, which in turn i have referenced in the CMS->Pages->Home Page content by the following code

```
{{block type="core/template" template="theme/home_banner.phtml"}}
```

In my home_banner.phtml I have called tags/popular.phtml to display the popular tags.

```
<div class="last-posts-grid clearfix">

     <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('tag/popular.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

</div>
```

However the tags are not being displayed even though the anchor tag which says "view all tags" id getting called correctly. The ul class="tags-list" is also visible in the page source but the tags themselves are not visible. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You made a small mistake in the template file. Your template file has to be as below:

```
<div class="last-posts-grid clearfix">

     <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('tag/popular')->setTemplate('tag/popular.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

</div>
```

I tested this and its working fine.. Hope this helps..

Comment: How to call feedback form phtml file in homepage?